# ??? ?? and other fake instead cyrillic from mobilefirst 8.0 java adapters

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have bad display of cyrillic characters from mobilefirst 8.0 java adapters in Chrome and other browsers. Swagger in mfpconsole can display cyrillic content correctly, but can\t display cyrillic from exceptions.

Exception http response Content-Type header have charset=ISO-8859-1, if that matters.

I get content in java adapter

```
String responsetext = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity(),"UTF-8")
```

Comment: Do you have a more complete example? Can you provide a .zip of your adapter with this issue?

Comment: thank you for the question. problem solved. my desktop have english system and mobile first or jax-rs framework sends charset=ISO-8859-1 instead charset=ISO-8859-5, what is cyrillic charset. it`s posible to specify encoding for Servlet request at jax-rs and all response headers will marked and body prodused in specified encoding.

Comment: Igor please write this as an answer and not a comment(!)

Comment: ////////////ok.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved. my desktop have english system and mobile first or jax-rs framework sends charset=ISO-8859-1 instead charset=ISO-8859-5, what is cyrillic charset. it`s posible to specify encoding for Servlet request at jax-rs and all response headers will marked and body prodused in specified encoding.